# Cannot make HTTP requests to Ocelot Gateway service from angular pod on kubernetes cluster

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, kubernetes, ocelot

I have ASP.NET CORE 6.0 application where Ocelot functions as an entry point for other microservices. All system is now deployed on Kubernetes. Besides, I have an Angular Application with RESTFUL API calls. The problem is that I cannot send Requests from the frontend to the backend using the Kubernetes services names.

I have tested the Ocelot Gateway on Kubernetes by adding a LoadBalancer Service. Everything works fine until this point. Below is the code for the **Ocelot Gateway JSON file**:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "catalogapi-clusterip-srv",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowScopes": []
      }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://homey-gateway-clusterip-srv:80"
  }
}
```

The Kubernetes Yaml file for the Gateway:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: homey-gateway-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: homey-gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: homey-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: homey-gateway
          image: ******
          imagePullPolicy: Always 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: homey-gateway-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: homey-gateway
  ports:
    - name: homey-gateway
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

I have also added a LoadBalancer for the Gateway to test if the routes are working fine

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: homey-gateway-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: homey-gateway
  ports:
    - name: homey-gateway-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9090
      targetPort: 80
```

Apparently, The LoadBalancer functioned as expected and I can see that routes are working perfectly.

Now, the Angular application:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: homey-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: homey
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: homey
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: homey
          image: *****
          imagePullPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: homey-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: homey
  ports:
    - name: homey
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

To test it locally I have added a NodePort to make sure that I can get the application on the browser.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: homey-srv
  labels:
    name: homey
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: homey
  ports:
    - nodePort: 32391
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

This works also fine.

Now I want to make API HTTP calls from the frontend to the backend. I tried by imminently using the Kubernetes backend clusterip name like: `http://homey-gateway-clusterip-srv:80`. However, this does not work and resulted in `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

The only way it works is by using the port I have exported in the LoadBalancer to test the Gateway so: `http://localhost:9090`.

I have seen a similar issue here in Stackoverflow: [Cannot make GET request to service from angular pod on kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118238/cannot-make-get-request-to-service-from-angular-pod-on-kubernetes-cluster)

Therefore, I have added an Ingress networking for the backend and frontend as followed:
`Backend:`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-homey-backend-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /backend
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: homey-gateway-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 80
```

and `Frontend:`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-homey-frontend-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /frontend
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: homey-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 80
```

**This approach does not work** I am getting `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`

I am not sure how to do this or how to configure it. Please help me by sharing the steps I need to follow, or at least tell me if I need to modify anything in the Ocelot Gateway file or in Kubernetes configurations. I have spent a lot of time on this with no results.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a very similar issue for the last few days. I have a Blazor SPA, a Duende Identity Server, and an Ocelot API gateway, which sits in front of my internal services I don't want exposed externally.

My specific issue is that my Blazor SPA (frontend) can't get past my ocelot-gateway because the gateway has trouble connecting to the identity server.

Blazor SPA ---> Ingress Proxy at (https://ocelot-gateway.com) ---> Ocelot Gateway Pod -x-> Identity Server via Ingress (https://identity.com)

**I still haven't figured it out, but maybe my files can help you spot some differences in your setup and help you since our problems are pretty similar**

*As far as things you can try:*

1. Enabling your kubernetes cluster for ingress. For minikube, look [here](https://Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler%5B3%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Exception%20occurred%20while%20processing%20message.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20System.InvalidOperationException:%20IDX20803:%20Unable%20to%20obtain%20configuration%20from:%20%27System.String%27.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20---%3E%20System.IO.IOException:%20IDX20804:%20Unable%20to%20retrieve%20document%20from:%20%27System.String%27.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20---%3E%20System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:%20Network%20is%20unreachable%20(identity.com:443)). For KinD, look [here](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/ingress/).
2. Adding the host you specified in your ingress manifest (if you're running locally) to your `/etc/hosts` file like so. Make sure to use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost. I can't remember where I read that, but basically I think it has to do with your local machine and docker defining localhost differently.

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 identity.com
> 127.0.0.1 pinpoint.com
> 127.0.0.1 ocelot-gateway.com
> ```

3. Maybe make sure you specify what host you're using in your ingress manifest.

.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-com
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /frontend
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: homey-clusterip-srv
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /backend
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: homey-gateway-clusterip-srv
            port:
              number: 80
```

I'm running my pods in a KinD K8s cluster.

I'm exposing my Blazor SPA, Identity Server, and Ocelot API gateway with Ingress objects.

#### ingress.blazor-spa.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pinpoint-spa
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: selfsigned-issuer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: pinpoint.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: pinpoint-spa
                port:
                  name: http
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - pinpoint.com
      secretName: pinpoint-tls-cert
```

#### ingress.identity-server.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: identity-com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: selfsigned-issuer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: identity.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: identity-service
                port:
                  name: http
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - identity.com
      secretName: pinpoint-tls-cert
```

#### ingress.ocelot-gateway.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ocelot-gateway-com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: selfsigned-issuer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ocelot-gateway.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ocelot-gateway
                port:
                  name: http
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ocelot-gateway.com
      secretName: pinpoint-tls-cert
```

Here are my Service manifests.

#### svc.blazor-spa.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pinpoint-spa
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: pinpoint-spa
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
      protocol: TCP
```

#### svc.identity-server.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: identity-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: identity-service
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
      protocol: TCP
```

#### svc.ocelot-gateway.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ocelot-gateway
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: ocelot-gateway
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
      protocol: TCP
```

Here's my `ocelot.json`.

```
"GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://ocelot-gateway.com",
    "ServiceDiscoveryProvider": {
      "Namespace": "default",
      "Type": "kube"
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps somehow!